# Read raster data in Matlab

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, matlab

I have a GeoTIFF image (satellite image) and I need to read the values of every pixel to calculate the sum.

How do I do that?

I'm new in both Matlab and the geographic field.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the mapping toolbox, https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geotiffread.html

If you don't,
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29425-geotiff-reader

This is a simple Google-able question.